# developer.apple.com change bundle ID

Tags: ios

I have an iOS project which is listed on developer.apple.com, so it has a certificate, but it has no bundle ID.  It has never been submitted to iTunes Connect.  I have added the ID to Xcode, but iTunes Connect does not see it.  Therefore I cannot submit it.  I can't see any way to add the ID on developer.apple.com.  So as far as I can see, there is no way to get iTunes to let me submit it.

Comment: Create another app id with different bundle identifier in iTunes connect and use that one?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that somehow, the app had been changed from targeting iPhone/iOS to targeting Mac/Os/X.  Therefore the bundle identifier did not show up in XCode.  So I could not even assign one to the app.  After I figured that out and put in a proper bundle ID, I did basically as ldindu suggested: deleted the old app ID and created a new one with the correct bundle ID, and got new profiles.